# Accessing Storyboard from Class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have an object of the ViewController class in another file, not in VC.h/.m. VC.h is hooked up to the Main.storyboard. I'm not sure how to change the label.text of a storyboard label from the ViewController object that is created in another file.

I was informed it had something to do with the nib file of Main.storyboard or this line of code:`[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *)Main bundle:(NSBundle *)nil];` My storyboard file is just the default    `Main.storyboard`

I have initialized the labels of the VC object like so:
`self.myVCObject.label1 = [UILabel new]` and changed the value: `self.myVCObject.label1.text = @"StackOverflow" ;` but nothing is displayed in the IOS Simulator when the app is run. Is the problem due to the VC object being not properly linked to storyboard? How would I fix the problem?

Comment: Interesting use of the passive voice "I have been informed.". This leaves us in the dark about the identity of the informer, to his benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link an IBOutlet from your storyboard label to your View Controller class. Then you can control the label.

Comment: I've done this already, I think. To declare the label in VC.h's interface: `@property  (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UILabel *label1;`

Comment: @user3780245 Simply declaring it isn't enough, you have to wire it up. Interface builder will do this for you if you "right-click" drag from the storyboard into your code.

Comment: I have linked it to the VC file with the Control Drag. Everything is properly linked. My problem is that when I create a ViewController object, and try to edit the value of a label, it is not shown in the simulator. In MyOtherClass.h I have a `@property ViewController *VCObject` In the MyOtherClass.m: `self.VCObject.label1 = [UILabel new] //label1 is a label of VC`and`self.VCObject.label1.text = @"StackOverflow" ;` but the text doesn't change in the simulator when run. The debugger shows that VCObject.label in initialized.

Comment: You shouldn't need to re init the label `self.VCObject.label1 = [UILabel new]`. All the views in the storyboard is automatically instantiated

Comment: If I don't "re"init the label, the debugger tells me that it is set to nil, so I have to init the label. The label is now a part of the VCObject, so if init in VC.h, it wouldn't be until I init it as a part of VCObject.

Comment: @user3780245:Then you've done something wrong. Once you've linked the `UILabel` in the storyboard to the property in the View Controller then the `UILabel` is non-nil.  You should be accessing the property in code using `self.label1.text` and you should not be declaring a new view controller object.

Comment: Yes I know this now, thank you, but I want to change the label from another class, so where would I access the first VC objet made, that is linked to the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerWithLabel"];

vc.label1.text = @"Hello world";
```

[image]

Comment: This also doesn't work... I have the VC files that have the methods for each button, but then a separate class file to do calculations and change the values of the labels. If everything is in just the VC class, and no separae classes, then everything works, but when I create a VC object, nothing happens to the text of the label, even with the method above.

Comment: Forr my propgram, I want the code above to be split. The declarations and initializations in VC.h/.m and the `vc.label1.text = @"Hello world";` to be in another file. So should the `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerWithLabel"];` be in the VC.m file? I think it should.

Comment: If you are already displaying that VC , then no need to instantiate a new VC. `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is creating a NEW instance of that VC (say VC2), but if you already showing VC1, and doing changes on VC2, of course nothing will happened, because VS2 and VS1 are not the same! So, if you already showing VC, than do your stuff in - (void)viewDidLoad; method of that VC.

Comment: I guess I have to do that, but I wanted to make it so that the other class makes a VC object and changes a label from there, not from VC, So changing the value of things in VC1 from VC2 and having that displayed on the screen. I didn't really understand before that that the View created an object of VC. Is there any way to access that object? Where is it declared? Thank you.